# Pop Many first n items in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, slice

> I have this document i need to update
> {
> "_id" : "1234",
> "arr" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> }

I want to pop the first n items from the array.
I thought about doing something like this:

```
 db.collection.update({
      _id: "1234"
    },
    {
      "$push": {
        "arr": {
          "$each": [],
          "$slice": {`n-arr.length`}
        }
      }
    })
```

Is there a way to use the expression {n - 'arr.length'} in the slice section?
Thanks..."

Answer (score 1):

use update pipeline

```
db.collection.update({_id:"1234"},
[
      {
        $addFields: {
          gg : {$filter:{
            input:"$arr",
            as:"z",
            cond:{$gte:[{$indexOfArray:["$arr","$$z"]},5]} // 5 is n first item
        }}
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          arr: "$gg",
          _id: 1,
          
        },
      },
    ]
)
```

Comment: in my exmaple the out put for arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is [6,7,8,9] did want it ?

Comment: your example doesnt work for me 2: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GCLlVWQZlC7

Comment: i checked in your query you set id as string and query the id as interger that was  problem

Comment: check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-3g4Y1IHtW